# opencart 1.5.6.4 version little update

Tags: opencart

I want to change this info from the product section.

[image]

"In stock" to be in a different color and in larger letters.

If anyone can be useful to me I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use free extension for than from OpenCart Marketplace

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=6782&sort=rating&page=8